# jQuery dialog not working on IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is the jQuery dialog really not compatible with IE 7 or i'm just doing something wrong?
(of course it might be the latter)

i have this code to load the jQuery dialog and it's working fine in all browser except IE7 and lower versions.

```
...

jQuery("#divDialog").dialog({
   modal: true,
   width: winWidth,
   height: winHeight,
   title: title,
   position: "center",
   close : function() {
       alert('Dialog Closed')
   }
  });
```

is there any way to have this working on IE 7?
thanks in advance for your advises..

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: what is your jQuery version? where do you set winWidth and winHeight? give us a bit more context please.

Comment: actually there really are no errors, even when i've checked it on fiddler. the dialog is just not displayed.

Comment: which jQueryUI and jQuery version? Errors in console?

Comment: It should work on IE7. We cant see where you call the JQuery dialog (function or document.ready() etc) or how the actual div "#divDialog" looks like. Have you tried creating a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the 2.x branch of jQuery, it is **not** compatible with IE7 (or 8):
http://jquery.com/browser-support/

> ```
>         Internet Explorer
> ```
>
> jQuery 2.x:          9+

If you need IE7 support, you should bump down to the 1.x branch, as it supports IE6 and up.